# ASP.NET Web Dev: Map one directory to another?

Tags: asp.net, iis

We are thinking of renaming our web directory schema to be more user friendly. However, we need any URL requests for the old directory structure to forward to the new one. so....

How do I forward requests for all of these:

http://mydomain.com/OLDdirname/

http://mydomain.com/OLDdirname/samesubdir/

http://mydomain.com/OLDdirname/samesubdir/samescript.aspx

to each of these respectively:

http://mydomain.com/NEWdirname/

http://mydomain.com/NEWdirname/samesubdir/

http://mydomain.com/NEWdirname/samesubdir/samescript.aspx

Any suggestions and perhaps some general guidance as far as gotchas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a number of things to do something like this. Basically, you're doing URL Rewriting. One of these products should help you get the job done:

- [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)
- [IIS Rewrite](http://www.qwerksoft.com/products/iisrewrite/)
- [opURL](http://www.opcode.co.uk/components/rewrite.asp)
- [IIRF](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRF.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I use IIRF on many of my websites, and it has always worked without failing. You use regular expressions to define the rules, and it takes care of the rest. It would be extremely easy to setup a few redirects using IIRF.

http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRF.aspx